Incosistent access of the array entries of an indexed array
I'm not sure how to describe or even title this issue but I feel the psuedo code explains it well. I have a multidimensional array called $data (4 levels) and some php code as follows:
    $data = [
             'a'=>['b'=>['c'=>['text','text','text'],
                         'ca'=>['1','1.5','2']
                        ],
                   'ba'=>['c'=>['text','text','text'],
                          'ca'=>['1','1.5','2']
                         ]
                  ],
             'a1'=>['b'=>['c'=>['text','text','text'],
                          'ca'=>['1','1.5','2']
                        ],
                   'ba'=>['c'=>['text','text','text'],
                          'ca'=>['1','1.5','2']
                         ]
                  ], 
            ]; 

    $new_array = [];
    
    foreach($data as $a=>$bs){
        foreach($bs as $b=>$cs){
            foreach($cs as $c=>$d){
                $new_array[$c][$b][$a] = $d;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //I don't know why ...
    
    print_r($new_array);//works, including indices
    
    print_r($new_array['known_index']);//displays nothing, no errors or warnings
    
    print_r($new_array[0]);//displays nothing, no errors or warnings
    
    print_r(current($new_array));//works

I tried enclosing the index variables in double quotes and I have worked around the problem overall. I just don't know what's going on and it feels like I should. PHP 8.2

I wouldn't be able to answer this anyway, but in my experience pseudo-code is always a lot less helpful than real code - a minimal but complete repro, including sample data (but only enough to demonstrate the problem).

Some example data is a great help to be able to reproduce any issue - that then helps to solve it.

foreach($cs as $c=$d) is invalid syntax.

i fixed a couple of typos that would have generated errors if they were in the original code. But to avoid distraction ...

the only thing I changed in the code i posted is the variable names. otherwise it is the actual code i'm using ....

would this work better in a data science group? these types of manipulation often come from web scraping data that needs to be transformed. They may have come across this more often. I.e. making highly customized associative arrays ....

Please [edit] your question to include any new code/data/info so it's clear, formatted properly and makes the question a coherent whole. Stackoverflow works primarily on the questions and answers. Comments are just a sideshow to briefly request clarification or make suggestions. It's not a discussion forum, and code in comments is usually hard to read beyond the very briefest snippets. Thanks

it seemed like an unnecessary additional clutter...no. we can't tell you how to process data we've never seen. We need a [mre] of the problem. See also [ask]

added the data array to make the code clearer ...

@Dyson - I did feel that I followed that advice. I guess I should have been clearer that I wasn't looking to have my code fixed. I wanted to know, for 'any multi dimensional array' what might cause the behavior described in my question. I did include how I 'processed' said array, which I can't see how more than that is required to venture an answer. Overall, I'm not stuck so please don't bother yourself with such an inadequately rendered question. Thanks for the advice though.

edited again since there are no numerals in the keys of the original data.

I see you found an answer you're happy with. But just in regards to the code you've now posted (thanks for updating the question, btw), you said it doesn't produce any errors or warnings, but it does output warnings when used with your sample data - demo: https://3v4l.org/40ueOj (scroll right to the bottom of the output box). Maybe you just don't have PHP set up to output warnings in your environment?

Turns out this question should be moved to Data Science or similar. The problem was the web scrape. Hidden HTML tags were breaking the indices. Since the array is built in so many places, from so many sources it's easiest, (not optimal) to fix it in situ ...
$a = is_string($a) ? trim(strip_tags($a)):$a;
$b = is_string($b) ? trim(strip_tags($b)):$b;
$c = is_string($c) ? trim(strip_tags($c)):$c;

//Associative indices now working as expected

PHP associative and indexed arrays are different.
Associative arrays uses named keys --- strings, to access the variable data. Your code generates an associative array, so using
var_dump($new_array[1]) // wont work
var_dump($new_array['ca']) // will work

Indexed arrays uses numeric values, just like a regular array would
Accessing your new array, we could:
foreach ($new_array as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($new_array[$key]);
}

I do not know if it would be useful but we can force an index array implementation using $array[] = ..
$new_new_array = [];
foreach ($new_array as $data) {
    $new_new_array[] = $data;
}
var_dump($new_new_array[1]); // this works

I can only manage to do this at the very end because your data processing requires the keys to be strings.
